# jQuery selectors tool

Tags: jquery, browser, add-in

I'm looking for some kind addon for browser (firefox, opera, ie, chrome, etc...), which can easily highlight element(s), which I define by jQuery selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [Firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11905/) Firebug extension?

Here's a short [screencast with jQuery integration](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/Firefinder-Add-on-for-Firebug-Add-on-for-Firefox.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Selectors](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kflfpppkpdjeodcbbcicnkpbpefebeli)

- Extension for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This one is from the author of the book "jQuery in Action" which is an excellent resource.

http://www.bibeault.org/jqueryinaction/chapter2/lab.selectors.html

Also found this one which looks good:

http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/